# Textmate option-delete no-wrap

Tags: text-editor, textmate

I'm curious if anyone has figured out a way to prevent TextMate from deleting the next "word" if passing a newline. For example, in most editors...

```
output += chunk.toString(); 

})|<-
```

option-delete from the caret at this point will remove `})`

```
output += chunk.toString();

|<-
```

option-delete from this point will remove the `\n`.

```
output += chunk.toString();
|<-
```

in a lot of editors, option-delete here will remove the final `\n` and place the caret at the end of `chunk.toString();|<-`. In TextMate, it removes the `\n` along with the next "word" `();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want <kbd>⌥⌫</kbd> to act as regular <kbd>⌫</kbd> when at the beginning of a line.

What you can do is overload <kbd>⌥⌫</kbd> for the case where you are at the beginning of a line (assuming you are using TextMate 2).

1. Edit → Macros → Start Recording (<kbd>⌥⌘M</kbd>)
2. Press delete (<kbd>⌫</kbd>)
3. Edit → Macros → Stop Recording (<kbd>⌥⌘M</kbd>)
4. Edit → Macros → Save Macro… (<kbd>⌃⌘M</kbd>)
5. Select a bundle for where to save your macro
6. Set key equivalent to option-delete (<kbd>⌥⌫</kbd>)
7. Set the scope selector to: `L:dyn.caret.begin`
8. Press <kbd>⌘S</kbd> to save the macro

Now pressing <kbd>⌥⌫</kbd> at the beginning of a line will act as if you pressed <kbd>⌫</kbd>.